# Getting additional NA column in read.delim in R

Tags: r, tabs, na, read.table

I am reading a text file in `R` of the form (from terminal)

```
hmi$ head -2 output_perl_hmi.txt 
1   CG10619-RB  tup 18864094    18864523    rev GFP_RNAi3_R1    0.870707220482784   
1   CG11050-RC  CG11050 6613278 6612484 rev GFP_RNAi3_R1    0.999267733859066
```

But when I read this in R using read.delim, it adds an additional column of NA at the end. I can just remove that column but I am wondering why it's creating that additional column and how can I avoid that when actually reading the file.

```
> d=read.delim("output_perl_hmi.txt", header=F)
> colnames(d) <-c("COUNT", "flybasename", "GENENAME", "START", "END", "TYPE","SAMPLE", "posterior_probability")
> head(d)
  COUNT flybasename GENENAME    START      END TYPE       SAMPLE posterior_probability NA
1     1  CG10619-RB      tup 18864094 18864523  rev GFP_RNAi3_R1             0.8707072 NA
2     1  CG11050-RC  CG11050  6613278  6612484  rev GFP_RNAi3_R1             0.9992677 NA
```

Comment: Try str(d) to see the structure of data before and after adding colnames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I must infer that your input file is delimited by tabs, even though you haven't specified this, because [`read.delim()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) defaults to `sep='\t'`.

Secondly, I strongly suspect that the reason you are getting an extra column of NA at the end of your data is that you have exactly one trailing tab at the end of every line of your input file. This results in `read.delim()` considering there to be one column after the trailing tab, which it parses as NA, because there's nothing there.

Below I demonstrate this. I have created two files, `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. The former contains your exact input file as you pasted it into your question, under assumptions that (1) it uses tab delimiters and (2) it has exactly one trailing tab on each line. The latter is the same, but without the trailing tab.

To clarify the whitespace, in my `cat` calls, I pass `-vet`, which shows tabs as `^I` and EOLs as `$`. Normally that would not be sufficient to completely disambiguate the data, but since we know that your input file has no circumflex or dollar, it will be unambiguous in this case.

```
system('cat -vet file1.txt;');
## 1^ICG10619-RB^Itup^I18864094^I18864523^Irev^IGFP_RNAi3_R1^I0.870707220482784^I$
## 1^ICG11050-RC^ICG11050^I6613278^I6612484^Irev^IGFP_RNAi3_R1^I0.999267733859066^I$
d <- read.delim('file1.txt', header=F );
d;
##   V1         V2      V3       V4       V5  V6           V7        V8 V9
## 1  1 CG10619-RB     tup 18864094 18864523 rev GFP_RNAi3_R1 0.8707072 NA
## 2  1 CG11050-RC CG11050  6613278  6612484 rev GFP_RNAi3_R1 0.9992677 NA
system('cat -vet file2.txt;');
## 1^ICG10619-RB^Itup^I18864094^I18864523^Irev^IGFP_RNAi3_R1^I0.870707220482784$
## 1^ICG11050-RC^ICG11050^I6613278^I6612484^Irev^IGFP_RNAi3_R1^I0.999267733859066$
d <- read.delim('file2.txt', header=F );
d;
##   V1         V2      V3       V4       V5  V6           V7        V8
## 1  1 CG10619-RB     tup 18864094 18864523 rev GFP_RNAi3_R1 0.8707072
## 2  1 CG11050-RC CG11050  6613278  6612484 rev GFP_RNAi3_R1 0.9992677
```

A good solution is therefore to strip trailing whitespace from the input file prior to reading it into R. (Note: I looked into using the `strip.white`, `colClasses`, and `col.names` arguments of `read.table()` (which is called from `read.delim()`, relaying the `...` to it) to solve the problem by automatically stripping whitespace or ignoring extra columns, but nothing I tried worked.)

Also, for general interest and knowledge, if you have multiple trailing tabs, each would be taken by `read.delim()` as a separator, and thus you would receive a corresponding column in the returned data.frame for each such tab:

```
system('cat -vet file3.txt;');
## 1^ICG10619-RB^Itup^I18864094^I18864523^Irev^IGFP_RNAi3_R1^I0.870707220482784^I^I$
## 1^ICG11050-RC^ICG11050^I6613278^I6612484^Irev^IGFP_RNAi3_R1^I0.999267733859066^I^I$
d <- read.delim('file3.txt', header=F );
d;
##   V1         V2      V3       V4       V5  V6           V7        V8 V9 V10
## 1  1 CG10619-RB     tup 18864094 18864523 rev GFP_RNAi3_R1 0.8707072 NA  NA
## 2  1 CG11050-RC CG11050  6613278  6612484 rev GFP_RNAi3_R1 0.9992677 NA  NA
```

And just to be really complete here, I just tested `read.delim()` to see what it would do if the input lines contained inconsistent numbers of delimiters. It appears to respect the "widest" input line, meaning the returned data.frame will contain as many columns as necessary to cover the most-delimited line in the input file. All short lines will have NA in their rightmost cells that were not covered in that line.